# Reference for application of local cohomology to complex manifolds with points removed

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, local-cohomology

Reference request - I am looking at Dolbeault cohomology on compact complex manifolds (not Riemann surfaces) with points removed. I have been told that the key to doing this is to look at Local cohomology at the missing points (previous question some years ago). Is there a lecture series or textbook or paper which would explain how to apply local cohomology to this problem?

Problem - I am really not an expert in algebraic geometry, I am looking for a simple explanation using the basics of sheaf cohomology and differential geometry. This arose from problems in integrable systems and classical field theory (I really meant I am not an expert in algebraic geometry, but I hope to apply it!). I will have to calculate everything for the specific case of $\mathbb{CP}^1\times \mathbb{CP}^1$ minus a finite number of points.

Comment: I would start by thinking about Meyer-Vietoris, which applies to Dolbeault cohomology, using a covering of your manifold by two open sets: (1) a union of disjoint open sets, each a ball in some local coordinates around the points you want to puncture, any two of these coordinates balls having disjoint closure, and (2) the complement of some closed sets, each closed set a closed ball of smaller radius in one of those coordinate domains.